# AWS delete object when pre-signed URL loses its validity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delete-file, pre-signed-url

I was wondering if within AWS there was a way to have an S3 object be automatically deleted once the pre-signed url that has been generated to access the given object from the outside looses its validity...?
More specifically I am not particularly looking at anything fancy like Lambdas (although I guess this would be one approach?)

Bottom line is: is there a possibility to assign a 'lifetime' value to an S3 object to which a pre-signed URL has been generated?

Cheers

Comment: is it your bucket or someone else's ? do you have access to it ?. why do you want to assign a lifetime validity value?

Comment: Yes it is my Bucket. The Bucket is private. when I Upload stuff for other people to download, I generate a pre-signed URL with a lifetime of 1 hour. When the hour is over and the link expires I would like the S3 object to be deleted at the same time because in my use-case people download thhe content 'instantly' as soon as the data is downloaded.

Comment: are you asking that the moment user download the file it should be deleted from s3?

Comment: Preferably when the link expires. However, as soon as the download takes place would be possible too of course, but would not resolve the issue for the case in which a user doesn't download the object and the link expires..

Comment: for the case of link expires and you want to delete the object it will be easy but solving other issue might be tricky.

Comment: Well the case of deleting when link expires is precisely the question! Which approach would you take?

Comment: Not much sure but setting life cycle policies would work for you. DO you use client libraries for s3 operations?

Comment: I use the aws java sdk

Comment: No, there is no in-built feature to do what you want (as specified in your question) but, as you alluded to, you could probably build something using a scheduled Lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this.

Most significant is the fact that S3 is not aware of the existence of pre-signed URLs.  When you generate a pre-signed URL, no interaction occurs with the service.  That's all done in your local code.  The service validates the signed URL when the request arrives.

And, of course, an infinite number of pre-signed URLs can be generated for each object... so, for most applications, this wouldn't be all that useful of a feature.

A lifecycle policy on your file-sharing bucket, to remove objects after a fixed period of time, would probably be the most straightforward solution.  This has a granularity of 1 day and a margin of error of +1/-0 days, since, policies are only evaluated daily.  (An object created today where the lifecycle policy is delete after 1 day will not be deleted tonight, it will be deleted tomorrow night.)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html